# I keep getting an SSL error when trying to use the Google Translate API

Tags: python-3.x, google-translate

I'm trying to test the Google Translate API for a script that I am writing, but I keep getting SSLErrors.

My original code when testing I simply tried

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
translator.translate(text = 'Emitido', src = 'pt', dest = 'en')
```

I then receive this error

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries 
exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, 
'[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed 
certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1076)')))
```

I then tried to disable verification by installing the cert

```
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
translator.session.cert = path/to/cert

translator.translate(text = 'Emitido', src = 'pt', dest = 'en')
```

But then I get this new SSLError

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='translate.google.com', port=443): Max retries 
exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib 
(_ssl.c:3833)')))
```

Does anyone have some feedback?